# how can we get notifications of DB changes without using NSFetchResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a requirement where i will fetch data per one page at time asynchronously from server and I need to save the data in core data.

I am using a UITableViewController which needs to be updated automatically when ever there is a change in DB.

How can I achieve this without using a fetchresultscontroller.

Answer (score 1):

`NSManagedObjectContext` provides notifications that may be useful:

- `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange`: Called when a managed object's values change.
- `NSManagedObjectContextWillSave`: Called before a save.
- `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave`: Called after a save.

Use `NotificationCenter` to subscribe to one or more of these. All of them provide information about what has changed-- see the documentation for details of that.